# .bash-PROFILE: No such file or directory in Mac terminal

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

When I open my terminal, I get the errors below and can't type new commands. Shutting down and restarting my Mac did not fix the problem. How can I fix this?

```
-bash: /Users/HabibAlejalil/.bash-PROFILE: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/HabibAlejalil/.bash-PROFILE: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/HabibAlejalil/.bash-PROFILE: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/HabibAlejalil/.bash-PROFILE: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/HabibAlejalil/.bash-PROFILE: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/HabibAlejalil/.bash-PROFILE: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/HabibAlejalil/.bash-PROFILE: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/HabibAlejalil/.bash-PROFILE: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/HabibAlejalil/.bash-PROFILE: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/HabibAlejalil/.bash-PROFILE: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/HabibAlejalil/.bash-PROFILE: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/HabibAlejalil/.bash-PROFILE: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/HabibAlejalil/.bash-PROFILE: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/HabibAlejalil/.bash-PROFILE: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/HabibAlejalil/.bash-PROFILE: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/HabibAlejalil/.bash-PROFILE: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/HabibAlejalil/.bash-PROFILE: No such file or directory

[Process completed]
```

Comment: Can you paste the contents of ~/.bashrc?

Comment: *nod* -- this isn't a file that's referred to by out-of-the-box configuration, so there's been some kind of local customization or modification made. Without knowing exactly what that is, it's hard to speak to -- but your dotfiles (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, etc) are the place to start. Beyond that, questions about *using* your system, as opposed to writing scripts for it, are a better fit for [unix.se], [apple.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: @Sharad can't past.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. GoodLuck

Comment: @aminohn, why not? You can run GUI-based apps that don't require the Terminal, after all. Run a text editor, open the file, copy its contents, etc. If that editor is MacVim, then you can run `:e ~/.bashrc` to open the file and not need to worry about Finder hiding it from you. Not that such an action is likely to salvage this question's applicability *here*, but it means that when you re-ask it somewhere it's on-topic, you'll be able to include enough details to have a good chance of getting an answer.

Comment: `.bash-PROFILE` is not `.bash_profile`. Capitalization may or may not matter on MacOS depending on how your filesystem is formatted, but `-` vs `_` _always_ matters.

Comment: The easiest way to silence the error message is to just create the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out, which file tries to access `.bash-PROFILE`. Of course you can grep the usual suspects (.profile, .bashrc, .bash_profile etc.), but this does not guarantee that it will show up. If it doesn't, you should produce a trace of what is being performed:

I would first try to open a bash subshell by

```
bash -li
```

and look whether the error message shows up again. If it does (likely, but not for sure), repeat this test with

```
bash -lix
```

which will show you the culprit. If `bash -li` does **not** show the error, I would put a `set -x` at the beginning of `/etc/profile` and your `~/.bashrc` and open a new terminal.

Comment: Might also suggest setting a `PS4` to log filename and line number with `set -x` enabled.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: If the user has created really huge bash startup files, this could perhaps help. But usually we know basically what's going on in our startup files, and finding the offending the line, once we see the location in the trace, is not that difficult. But I think setting PS4 as an environment variable would be helpful in general for debugging. I will consider your idea for my own development process.